# After the condition of a select is met, show or hide further selects

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, select

I have the following question because I haven't found anything on the internet. I have created several selects with HTML. The select has the optiions yes / no. The first select checks whether the topic is relevant, if it is not relevant, then the remaining selects for the topic should disappear. I then send the evaluation of the selects with a button (evaluation with php), but would like to have the behavior, directly between the change from yes to no. I am open to all possibilities, be it CSS, HTML or JavaScript. In addition, all of my Selects are in a "div"

Comment: What do you mean "The checkboxes can be filled in with yes / no." ?

Comment: That I have the option yes or no in the checkboxes.

Comment: Checkboxes don't contain written options, they're just a tick (on / checked) or no tick (off / not checked). Maybe show us your HTML.

Comment: Oh guys, I'm sorry. Unfortunately I don't have any checkboxes, but selects. These then include yes or no. My mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your checkbox, you can add `onchange="changeChk()"` like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkId" onchange="changeChk()">
```

then in Javascript you can make disappear/appear other checkboxes in this function:

```
function changeChk() {
    if (document.getElementById('checkId').checked) {
        document.getElementById("otherchk").classList.remove("hidden");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("otherchk").classList.add("hidden");
    }
```

with a bit of css:

```
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Example where I surround the checkbox with a span to make the label disappear as well:

```js
function changeChk() {
    if (!document.getElementById('checkId').checked) {
        document.getElementById("spanDisappear").classList.remove("hidden");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("spanDisappear").classList.add("hidden");
    }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkId" onchange="changeChk()"> this will always be here
<span id="spanDisappear"><input type="checkbox" id="otherchk"> this will disappear</span>
```

If you have a select, it's (almost) the same.

On your select, you can add `onchange="changeValue()"` then in Javascript you can make disappear/appear other selects.

Example:

```js
function updateView() {
    if (document.getElementById('whateverDDL').value == "yes") {
        document.getElementById("spanDisappear").classList.remove("hidden");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("spanDisappear").classList.add("hidden");
    }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <select id="whateverDDL" onchange="updateView()"><option value="yes">Of course</option><option value="no">Absolutely not</option></select> this will always be here
</p>
<span id="spanDisappear"><input type="text" id="otherchk"> this will disappear</span>
```

Comment: Okay thank you very much. I would have one more question: What does the "checked" check? Is it checked with "Yes", or how can I understand that.

Comment: It checks whether the checkbox is ticked or not. I added a fiddle so that you can try the example. Just click on "Run code snippet".

Comment: I'm sorry. Unfortunately I don't have any checkboxes, but selects. These then include yes or no. My mistake! But this will help me in the future, thanks!